# is there a way to sort the columns of in admin models? django

Tags: python, django, sorting, admin

Sometimes we are able to click on the column then the table will be sorted by what's clicked BUT some are not clickable and I do believe those none clickable are because it's not the fields in the model that it's either a foreign key or M2M

I am wondering if there's a way to make them clickable to sort too?

for example of the following,

title and created_at are clickable but not SET

[image]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just guessing your models, but you get the idea.

```
def ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'set', 'created_at')

     def set(self, obj):
        return obj.set

    set.admin_order_field = 'set__name'
```

Comment: how do you get this field though? `set__name` like...where does the `__name` come from?

Comment: Well, if `set` is a related field on your model, and if it has a field say `name` then you get it using forward relation. As I said, I'm guessing the models you have.

Comment: I get what you mean now, but its giving me errors about cannot resolve keyword, only certain keywords can be used.  What can I can only use are the fields by the model itself.  Guess, I cannot use the field that's a `Foreign key` :(

Comment: Of course you can. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display This section down the bottom — “admin_order_field supports query lookups to sort by values on related models. This example includes an “author first name” column in the list display and allows sorting it by first name”.

Comment: Show me the model you have please.

Comment: You should ignore it and use this as of now: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display